# Is it possible to completely close an expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

Is there a way to completely shutdown/kill an Expo app as soon as it gets exited by the user(To the background) so when he opens it the next time it opens from the start?

I know there is `BackHandler.exitApp()` but that just exits the app and doesn’t close it completely so that’s not what i need.

Comment: No, there is no way to completely close the app.

Comment: Okay but is it possible to refresh a specific component then? I am displaying a QR Code and would need to keep it up to date because it has a timestamp in it and if the app doesn’t get closed the QR Code doesn’t update itself

Comment: can you please be a bit more specific? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an app that displays an QR Code that contains some information along with a timestamp in it. But the QR Code only generates when the app is opened the first time. So the QR Code never updates if an user never completely closes the app. So I need a way to update the QR Component in order to get a QR Code that contains an up to date timestamp. Is this understandable? Sorry i don’t know how to explain it properly

Comment: I am using react-native-qrcode-svg to create the code by the way